# Reverse for 'create' not found. 'create' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I want to create a tempfriends during creating Moneybook.

So i write a code in a create moneybook template but error occur :

> NoReverseMatch at /moneybooks/create/
>   Reverse for 'create' not found. 'create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I write a proper appname, write a urls.py, use single quote...ete but don't know how to achieve it.

**moneybook_form.html**

```
<div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="w-1/4">
                {{form.companion.label}} 
            </div>
            <div class="w-3/4 flex inline border-b my-2 py-3">
                <div class="w-3/4">
                    {{form.companion}}
                </div>
                <div class= "w-1/4 flex justify-center ">
                    <a href="{% url 'tempfriends:create' %}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a> #this part error occured
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if form.companion.errors %}
            {% for error in form.companion.errors %}
                ><span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

**config/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("cores.urls", namespace="cores")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("users/", include("users.urls", namespace="users")),
    path("tempfriends/", include("tempfriends.urls", namespace="tempfriends")),
    path("moneybooks/", include("moneybooks.urls", namespace="moneybooks")),
    path("moneylogs/", include("moneylogs.urls", namespace="moneylogs"))
]
```

**moneybooks/urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneybooks"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.moneybook_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneybook_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
]
```

**tempfriends/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "tempfriends"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.tempfriend_create.as_view(), name="create"),
]
```

**tempfriends/views.py**

```
class tempfriend_create(FormView):

    form_class = forms.CreateTempfriendForm
    template_name = "tempfriends/create.html"

    def get_current_user(request):
        current_user = request.user

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tempfriend = form.save()
        belongs_to = current_user
        form.instance.belongs_to = belongs_to
        tempfriend.save()
        return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
```

Comment: seeing your urlpatterns you probably need to use name instead of namespace in the path function.

Comment: thanks for the reply. you mean the config/urls.py? namesapce -> name???? , if you this is true, the error occur: include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name' ..

Comment: name is an argument of the path function and not incude

Comment: I just checked my urls.py and I am including my url files without the namespace parameter and it works.

Comment: @hendrikschneider wow. it works. but i don't know what happened... anyway. erase namespace work for me.

Comment: @dhooonk Would you mind to accept my comment as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked my urls.py and I am including my url files without the namespace parameter and it works.